# jquery submits form before confirmation is given

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a `JQuery` dialogue plugin which works fine except the form submits before the user is able to click on any of the buttons to confirm or not.  I have added `preventDefault` but depending on where I put it, it either stops the form submitting completely or is completely ignored and the forms just submits without confirmation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#perm_del_submit').click(function(ev){
      $.msgbox("Are you sure?", {  
        type: "confirm", 
        buttons: [
          {type: "submit", value: "Yes"},
          {type: "cancel", value: "No"}
        ]
      }, function(result) {
        if (result == 'Yes') {
          $('#audit_sort_form').submit();
        }
      });
    ev.preventDefault();   
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: what is the type of form control that has id perm_del_submit

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question?

Comment: what is `$("#perm_del_submit")` does that make more sense?

Comment: it is the id of the submit button

Comment: more precisely, what element is it. is it a button with type="button"? is a button with type="submit"? is it an input with type="button"? is it an input with type="submit"? is it an input with type="image"? Not that it really matters, because the problem has nothing to do with the type of button being used.

Comment: The problem here is going to be your usage of the $.msgbox plugin. Can you provide some documentation to it?

Comment: the plugin is from code canyon and this is the link http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-msgbox/92626

Comment: the button is a submit button

Comment: Try `type: "button"` rather than `type: "submit"`

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't submit

Comment: What in your code is being reached? add some logging and alerts, or if you understand how, use breakpoints or step through the code. In what order does it get executed? do you ever get to the message box? are any errors occurring? obviously something else isn't working because syntactically there's nothing wrong with your code, and the logic is relatively sound.

Comment: @KevinB, I have realised that the mysql that runs after the form submit is looking for $_post['perm_del_submit'] which is why I thought the form wasn't being posted, it seems it is but the trigger for the mysql isn't happening

Comment: That's because you aren't submitting it with the submit button. Don't look for that post param if you're going to post using `.submit`.

Answer (score 0):

The callback function fires after the confirm window is created. That is why it is calling submit before they even answer the confirm. According to the code, when it displays the confirm, it thinks it's processing is done, and next in the que is the callback function. You have to apply your submit function to the "click" event if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Should be as follows:      buttons: [
    {
      text: "OK",
      click: function() {
        //your callback function to test for submit
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Do not bind the handler to a "click" event, but to the form submit event (if I'm in a form and I tab to the submit button and hit enter, I've submitted the form but completely bypassed your handler function. This is not an uncommon occurrence, either).

If you want to do it the way you suggest, you also have to give your form a flag (I've used "submittable" in the example below) once the message box shows.

```
$('#audit_sort_form').on('submit',function(e) {
   var el = $(this),submittable = el.data('submittable');

   if(!submittable) {
    e.preventDefault();


      $.msgbox("Are you sure?", {  
        type: "confirm", 
        buttons: [
          {type: "submit", value: "Yes"},
          {type: "cancel", value: "No"}
        ]
      }, function(result) {
        if (result == 'Yes') {
         el.data('submittable',true);
         el.submit();
        }
      });
   }


});
```

Comment: You can do it without the flag, fyi. remove the if statement and the flag, and when you want to submit the form use `el[0].submit()`, it will bypass the submit callback you defined with jquery.

Comment: While you are correct, I think it would be confusing to the developer to bind a submit handler and not expect it to be executed under all conditions where the form is submitted, even programmatically. What if another button was added somewhere that submitted the form programmatically and all of a sudden this handler "didn't work"?

Comment: the form still doesn't submit

Comment: Right, but adding the flag doesn't change that fact, even with the flag you can still completely bypass that event handler with said other button.

Comment: @tatty27 - then you're doing something else wrong. Don't say "it doesn't work" without providing some sort of error message.

Comment: I wouod if I could but there is no error, the page refreshes but the form doesn't submit

Comment: @tatty27 - the page refreshes because the form submitted. That's what a form does when it submits.

Comment: @KevinB - it will if you use jQuery submit() method - which you should be using consistently if you are using it elsewhere.

Comment: sorry, my bad, the page is looking for the post of the submit button 'perm_del_submit' but because that isn't being used the mysql isn't being run

Comment: @tatty27 - It doesn't matter. If you have `<input type="submit" name="perm_del_submit" value="yourvalue">` in the form that is being submitted, then that value will get passed with the rest of the form data.

Comment: @Adam that's a difference of opinion, just because jquery is available doesn't mean you should always use it.

Comment: @KevinB - but if it is available and you are using it, then you should always use it. If it's available and you aren't using it, then you should never use it. It doesn't matter which way you do it as long as you do it consistently.

Comment: I'm using this because I am using the dialogue on all of the pages on this site and it works well for everything else, just not this.

Comment: That's irrelevant. The fact is it solves the problem and makes the code cleaner and easier to maintain by getting rid of the flag. That of course is my opinion and you are going to disagree with that on principal.

Comment: @tatty27 - without further code, I can't do anything else - the code I posted works. Perhaps you have other code that is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your actual submit button (#perm_del_submit) is an `<input type="submit"/>` ?
Make it a `<input type="button"/>` ?

Comment: hi, thanks for that but the same thing happens, the confirmation box shows, the page refreshes when yes is clicked but the actual form doesn't submit

Answer (score 0):

For validating forms or confirming form submission I recommend handling the form's `submit` event rather than the button's `click` event.  There's more than one way to submit a form, so unless you only care about when the form is submitted by clicking a specific button, handle the form submit event instead.

Another good habit to get into is to call `e.preventDefault()` first.  That way, if there is a JavaScript error, or a `return` statement within the function, the form submission is still cancelled.

```
$("#audit_sort_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    $.msgbox("Are you sure?", {  
        type: "confirm", 
        buttons: [
            {type: "submit", value: "Yes"},
            {type: "cancel", value: "No"}
        ]
    }, function(result) {
        if (result == "Yes") {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

When a form is submitted by calling the `submit()` method of the `<form>` element, the submit event is *not* called.  Also, the button is not included in the form post.  So, if your server-side handler depends on the value of the submit button being included, you'll have to spoof it with a hidden input.  If you have multiple buttons for the same form, and it matters to the server which button was clicked, put a hidden field in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="perm_del_submit" />
<input type="submit" value="a" />
<input type="submit" value="b" />
```

Set the value of the field when the button is clicked:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
    this.form.perm_del_submit.value = this.value;
});
```

Then, let the `submit` handler from above handle the form submission.  The hidden input value will have already been set, and will indicate which button triggered the form submission.